# HOw to access all the colors from within all the color arrays?

Tags: javascript

`[{name: "apple", color:["green", "red"]}, {name: "banana", color:["yellow"]}]`.
 Using for loop?

code that I tried:
 `for (i = 0; i < color.length; i++) { return color.length; }`

Comment: Yes you can use a loop to iterate over arrays. I would start reading here: http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html#h_FaGGgUI+MM .

Comment: This is what I tried but it is not working: for (i = 0; i < color.length; i++) { return color.length;
}

Comment: i am getting undefined. That is the error.

Comment: @Ann, you need to edit the question to include the relevant code that you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the map function for the array of objects and then a for loop for the inner property "color" of each object.

```
var fruits = [{
    name: "apple",
    color: ["green", "red"]
}, {
    name: "banana",
    color: ["yellow"]
}];

var colors = [];

fruits.map(function(fruit) {
    for (var i = 0; i <  fruit.color.length; i++) {
        colors.push(fruit.color[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks all. This is simple to understand for me.

Comment: This method will only get the first color from each color array

Comment: @Divide100 It works as supposed on my computer - try to console.log fruit.color[i] instead of returning so you'll see.

Comment: No.  this method works like charm since it was easy for me . All of them work but this work was easy for me so.

Comment: @VáclavZeman of course it will show me all the fruit if I log it to the console instead of returning. When it's logged instead of returning it will continue to iterate through the loop, returning will end the loop. Here is a fix for your issue: instantiate a new array before the loop, push the colors into that array within the loop, and return after looping is complete

Comment: @Divide100 Yes, you are right. I did not actually test the function with the return so I forgot about this. Thanks.

Comment: your earlier code was more right. map gives an array itself. This code give me 1, 2, 3 when console logged.

Comment: There was really an error. Can you try this - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ff4gg81v/1/) if it's ok?

Comment: This works. I console.logged `colors.push(fruit.color[i])` before. He is right.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a neat way to do what I think you want:

```
var all_colors = [{name: "apple", color: ["green", "red"]}, 
              {name: "banana", color: ["yellow"]}].reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b.color);
}, []);

// Note: this line uses ES6
var colors = Array.from(new Set(all_colors));
```

that outputs an array of all colors, removing duplicates:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea I am giving heads up to people who answered. This is something stackoverflow needs to bring in strict guidelines on negative points for answers that are wrong only. Plus one to you.

Comment: This seems like a great solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to loop through the objects in the array, then concatenate the colors from each object into a color array:

```js
var colorArr = [];
var arr = [{name: "apple", color:["green", "red"]}, {name: "banana", color:["yellow"]}];
for(var i in arr) {
  if(arr[i]['color']){
    colorArr = colorArr.concat(arr[i]['color']);
  }
}
```